# Connection timeout issue in Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I have been facing some weird connection timeout issues in Visual Studio Code.

I am writing a simple web crawler to read a website using the `requests` and `beautifulsoup4` packages in Python. I don't have any problem opening the URL in my web browsers (opens fine in Edge and Chrome), but when I say `request.get(url)`, then the request always times out. Also, when I try to install some additional packages using `pip`, it always times out. But the corresponding PyPI page opens fine on my web browser.

The funny thing is - I am facing this issue only when I work out of my company's office. I don't have this issue at all when I am working from my home. There shouldn't be a system-wide firewall or a network firewall, because if there is, then the sites shouldn't be opening on my browsers too, right?

I went to VS Code Preferences and checked the settings there. There's no proxy set up. There is nothing specifically that would block network requests from inside VS Code. Here are some screenshots showing what VS Code Settings looks like.

[image: Settings related to "proxy"]

[image: Settings related to "network"]

[image: Settings related to "connection"]

[image: Settings related to "timeout"]

I looked online and couldn't find much, since every question out there is regarding timeouts in SSH connections, which isn't relevant to me here. This official [site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network) here gives a bunch of URLs that need to be allowed by the firewall for VS Code to be able to connect to the network, but I don't know where to add them.

Is there something that I am missing? Any leads on how I can debug this issue? Or is it something that I'll have to take up with my company's network administrator?

TIA.